# Exporting data from table into excel with "xlxs"or "csv" extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, export-to-excel

I am using a export method in my controller to download data from table into excel file using this method:
here is my table in index file:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Marks)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Grade)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Marks)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Grade)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

and in my controller i have written this method which is triggered when u press the export button in index view:

```
 public ActionResult ExportData()
        {
            GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = db.Studentrecords.ToList();
            gv.DataBind();
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            Response.Charset = "";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return RedirectToAction("StudentDetails");
        }
```

everything is working fine the table gets downloaded into the excel file easily but when i open the file it gives this error in the start of open file that: 
The file format doesn't match.The file could be corrupted or unsafe.
The problem is causing mainly because file gets saved with xls format where as i want to save it in xlxs format how can that be possible?

Comment: This may causing your issue: `Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Marklist.xls");`. You can use `xlsx` extension there. Also I suggest you to drop `Response.Output.Write` and return `FileStreamResult`/`FileContentResult` instead.

Comment: how to replace this Response.Output.Write ?

Comment: i have tried adding xlsx in Response.AddHeader it doenot solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

To export the MVC view data into an Excel file, I am using the ClosedXml Library.

[image]

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        var gv = new GridView();
        gv.DataSource = this.GetEmployeeList();
        gv.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        Response.Charset = "";
        StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);

        gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);

        Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        return View("Index");

    }
```

Link to Complete Article [Article Link](http://www.mukeshkumar.net/articles/mvc/export-data-in-excel-file-with-asp-net-mvc)